# Why is there 5GB of unallocated space on my disk on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10

Why do I have 5.59GB of unallocated space on Disk 2? See the picture:

[image]

what is it for? is there a way to delete it?

What is the difference between Disk 1 and Disk 2? Why Disk 1 does not have an unallocated space?

Comment: Can you resize the partition to its left to include this unallocated space?

Comment: @harrymc I did not try to resize the partition, but when I delete the partition, the free space on Disk 2 is not merged, but there are still two unallocated segments.

Comment: @harrymc currently I can't resize, because there is no such item in the menu (probably because it is a stripped volume)

Comment: Can you replace the disk layout image by the current situation and with no formatting going on?

Comment: @harrymc replaced (Disk 1 + Disk 2 = stripped volume I:)

Comment: Asking _"how do I delete unallocated space"_ is like asking _"how do I remove emptiness from my room"_. Unallocated = there's nothing there.

Comment: Note that it is bad practice to raid together drives from different SKUs.

Comment: @Brian But RAID-ing drives from the same batch is also a bad practice, because failures of such drives are correlated and thus reliability of the array is decreased. With just 2 disks I'd rather just buy 2 different but similar models than try to hunt down 2 of the same model but from different batches.

Comment: @gronostaj: Agreed, though this doesn't really apply to Raid0.  With Raid0, having simultaneous failures is fine (or possibly preferable), since any failure will corrupt the entire array.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The partitions on disks 1 and 2 need to be the same size because you created a striped (RAID 0) volume. One drive is a 250 GB drive, the other one a 256 GB drive, hence the size difference.

If you don’t need RAID 0 performance, you can also create a spanned volume. It has no special characteristics except that it can be backed by multiple non-contiguous extents of drive space.

Comment: is it possible to expand system volume `C:` with spanned volume in this way? So I would have 1TB system drive?

Comment: No, that’s not possible. The system volume (and separate boot volumes) can only be mirrored.

Answer (score 11):

They're configured as a Striped Disk (like a software RAID 0 more or less) so in order to do that both disks need to have the same size. It's always adjusted to the size of the less capacity disk. You can't remove neither resize that unallocated space until you decide to remove the Striped configuration.
As to why that difference in size... Well, that could be because are from different vendors and therefore not "exactly" the same size.